# Groovy: What's wrong with this "Hello World" program?

Tags: groovy

This does not work:

```
$ groovy -e 'println "Hello, world!"'
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script_from_command_line: 1: unexpected char: 0xFFFF @ line 1, column 23.
   println "Hello, world!
                         ^

1 error
```

However, putting a space between the last double- and single-quote works...

```
$ # groovy -e 'println "Hello, world!"'
$   groovy -e 'println "Hello, world!" '
Hello, world!
```

... even though `bash` seems to be able to correctly handle the trailing `"'` pair (i.e., without any intervening space) as follows:

```
$ echo '"Hello, world!"'
"Hello, world!"
```

Also, parenthesizing the `println` argument works just fine:

```
$ groovy -e 'println ("Hello, world!")'
Hello, world!
```

Now, I would like to know why the very first case does not work.

I'm using:

- bash, version "4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
- groovy, version 2.1.3

Comment: This isn't a _bash_ problem, it's a groovy issue. (_zsh_, _csh_ and _dash_ all exhibit the save behavior.)

Comment: Weird.  0xFFFF is [not even a defined codepoint in Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffff/index.htm).

Comment: @RayToal - `0xFFFF` is -1, or EOF (end of file).

Comment: That may be, but that means the error is pretty dumb.  If you are going to say you have a *char* and you give what looks like a codepoint, you shouldn't make up a meaning for it!  I thought the Groovy folks would be smarter than that.  There is no char 0xFFFF in Unicode, so they should use a different wording.  #pedantic

Comment: They're claiming it's a Commons CLI issue, but I've seen the same problem in Groovy Console. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4828

Comment: This is not a bug in `bash`, but rather a bug in Groovy. See the comments above.

Comment: It is a Commons CLI bug. There's a task to change the version as soon it is available http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5282

Comment: @RayToal, the wording is not from us, it is from antlr, as is the message text

Comment: any update regarding this?

Comment: I'm getting this error when I combine `sh '''` with `sh` without `'''`

Comment: It's fixed! When I type `groovy -e 'println "Hello, world!"'` in bash I get a bunch of warnings and then `Hello, world!`.

Comment: Updated link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4828

Answer (score 4):

As BDKosher already stated, this is a bug from Apache Commons CLI. Groovy wants to update to 1.3, but the CLI folks take their time with that version and it contains incompatibilities.

And as I wrote in an above comment already 0xFFFF is used by antlr to show the end of the file, it does not have to be a valid unicode character for that. The wording was criticized because of this, but the wording is from the parser generator antlr, not from us.

Answer (score 0):

I see an exception running version 2.1.3 and Java 6:

```
    C:\Users\mwest>groovy -e 'println "Hello, world!"'
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script_from_command_line: 1: expecting ''', found '<EOF>' @ line 1, column 9.
   'println
```

Curiously reversing the quotes works

```
C:\Users\mwest>groovy -e "println 'Hello, world!'"
Hello, world!
```

Answer (score -2):

This runs fine on OSX.  I think this error has to do with improper termination.  The following runs on linux:

```
groovy -e 'println "Hello, world!";'
```