# How to execute groovy jar in unix- ERROR

Tags: unix, groovy

I have a groovy project developed in eclipse , which has a package(hello) and a groovy class(helloWorld.groovy) inside it. I have exported the jar (Say HelloWorld.jar). I am trying to execute this jar in unix by :-

```
groovy -cp /tmp/HelloWorld.jar hello.helloWorld
```

But get the below error :-

```
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/hello.helloWorld (/tmp/hello.helloWorld)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/hello.helloWorld (/tmp/hello.helloWorld)
```

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth-- I did not find anything realted to my question in the link you provided.

Comment: Post your class please.  Without it, we're shooting in the dark

Comment: @tim_yates: I think this is more that that's not the correct CLI syntax for `groovy`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A class is just a declaration unless it contains static methods.

You can create an instance of the class and call a method from a command line script.

HelloWorld.groovy

```
package hello
class HelloWorld {
    def main() { println "Hello World!" }
}
```

Compile and jar:

```
groovyc HelloWorld.groovy
jar -cf HelloWorld.jar hello
```

Execute:

```
groovy -cp HelloWorld.jar -e 'new hello.HelloWorld().main()'
```

---

You can call a static method without creating an instance of the class:

HelloWorld.groovy

```
package hello
class HelloWorld {
    static main() { println "Hello World!" }
}
```

Compile and jar:

```
groovyc HelloWorld.groovy
jar -cf HelloWorld.jar hello
```

Execute:

```
groovy -cp HelloWorld.jar -e 'hello.HelloWorld.main()'
```

Comment: groovy -cp HelloWorld.jar
 -e 'new hello.HelloWorld().main()'
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script_from_command_line: 1: expecting ''', found '<EOF>' @ line 1, column 5.
   'new
       ^

Comment: I had to use double quotes in cmd.exe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078537/groovy-whats-wrong-with-this-hello-world-program

Answer (score 0):

The groovy command is usually used to compile and run groovy files in a single step.  The command line argument is a script file, not a class name.

If your groovy script has been compiled into `class` files, run it with Java.  For example:

```
java -cp /tmp/HelloWorld.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.7.jar hello.helloWorld
```

Comment: executed : java -cp /tmp/HelloWorld.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.7.jar hello.helloWorld  

getting error :- 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
.......
Could not find the main class: hello.helloWorld. Program will exit.

contains of META-INF\MANIFEST.MT in HelloWorld.jar
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: hello.helloWorld

Comment: Does $GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.7.jar exist?  That file must exist.  Ensure the GROOVY_HOME environment variable is set and adjust the version number as necessary.

Comment: This is what worked on windows: `java -cp "Hello.jar;%groovy_home%\embeddable\groovy-all-2.4.4.jar" hello.Hello`